# jquery dialog works but not when buttons added in Firefox and IE, works in Chrome; FIXED see comments

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a working dialog but when I attempt to add the code so that an "OK" button is shown it fails to work.  No javascript errors.  The dialog starts out hidden with CSS.

...

javascript in `document.ready`

works...

```
var downtimeDiv = $("#downtimeDialog");

    downtimeDiv.dialog({        
        width: 770,
        height: 250,
        modal: true,
        title: "Downtime Scheduled",
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        position: ['center', 'top'],
        closeOnEscape: false,
        open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog).hide(); }
    });
downtimeDiv.show();    
downtimeDiv.dialog("open");
```

doesn't work...

```
var downtimeDiv = $("#downtimeDialog");

    downtimeDiv.dialog({        
        width: 770,
        height: 250,
        modal: true,
        title: "Downtime Scheduled",
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        position: ['center', 'top'],
        closeOnEscape: false,
        open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog).hide(); },
        buttons: {"OK": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}}
    });
downtimeDiv.show();    
downtimeDiv.dialog("open");
```

firebug doesn't show any error but the dialog fails to show, it's css stays display:none;

Thanks for any help.

Ok I've found the problem.  I was missing a javascript include.

Adding http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js

fixed the issue for firefox and IE.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your code.

add a closing paranthesis after buttons

```
buttons: {"OK": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}}
```

Use the [recommended syntax](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Dialog#option-buttons):

```
buttons: [
    {
        text: "Ok",
        click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    }
]
```

Please notice the `[` and `]`

Comment: Mistake in copy paste, good eye.  I edited the post to have the missing end bracket as it is in my code.  Issue is the same though.  Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the closing `}` at the end of buttons element.

Yours

```
buttons: {"OK": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
```

The correct one

```
buttons: {"OK": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}}
```

Comment: Just noticed that the button works in chrome but not in firefox or IE. The missing bracket was a copy paste error.